# Calendarize data monthly based on start/stop dates in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (with a few hundreds of thousand rows) with records containing a value and related start/stop dates. For example:

```
Start Date; End Date; Value
2010-01-15; 2010-02-15; 100
2010-02-15; 2010-03-10; 50
```

Using SQL, how do I redistribute 'Value' evenly across the relevant months based on start and stop dates, turning it into something like this?:

```
Year; Month; Calendarized Value
2010; 01; 50
2010; 02; 75
2010; 03; 25
```

The span between start and end dates may represent a few days or multiple months.

Comment: Some more explanation needed here... for start how did you separate those two registries into 3, can you explain the distribution?

Comment: And read this [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) It will help us to help you.

Comment: Why is the first entry not split 53 in January and 47 in February? And why is the second entry not split 29 in February and 21 in March? (i.e. Why are they not split proportionally by the number of days?) So to my eye the totals should be 2010/01=53, 2010/02=76, 2010/03=21.

Answer (score 0):

This query should provide what you are looking for.  It will distribute evenly by number of months between the start and end dates, and will work even if the dates are only a few days apart.  I'm not sure if you have a primary key or unique ID on your table.  If so, use that in place of this part:

```
    AND PRIOR start_date = start_date
    AND PRIOR end_date = end_date
    AND PRIOR value = value
```

My assumption here is that each start_date + end_date + value is unique.

```
SELECT
    y "Year", m "Month", SUM(distr_value) "Calendarized Value"
FROM (
    SELECT
        TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, LEVEL-1), 'mm') m
      , TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(start_date, LEVEL-1), 'yyyy') y
      , value / (MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(end_date, 'MON'), TRUNC(start_date, 'MON'))+1) distr_value
    FROM
        my_table
    CONNECT BY
        LEVEL <= MONTHS_BETWEEN(TRUNC(end_date, 'MON'), TRUNC(start_date, 'MON'))+1
        AND PRIOR start_date = start_date
        AND PRIOR end_date = end_date
        AND PRIOR value = value
        AND PRIOR sys_guid() IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY
    y, m
ORDER BY
    y, m;
```